# GAE Cloud SQL connection timed out

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

When I try to run the database locally and the server is asking for requests everything works fine but when I try to upload the database and the server to GAE Im always getting this error:

```
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xx.xx' ([Errno 110] connection timed out)")
```

Im trying to accomplish a stable connection without having to run mysql on my local machine.

Thanks for anyone helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use Cloud SQL from App Engine without having to run your own MySQL instance. To do so, you can have a look at the information in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/).

Make sure that you are configuring your environment variables correctly (you can do so directly from the `app.yaml` configuration file) and importing the `MySQLdb` library, as explained in the [corresponding section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/#setting-up) in that same page.

There you will find some sample code and also additional information regarding how to test your application both in the development and production environments.

Comment: is it possible to do that with flask framework along with sql alchemy? sorry that's something i forgot to mention. I saw the documentation about doing it with flask and sql alchemy but there is one line "export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=mysql+pymysql://[USER_NAME]:[PASSWORD]@127.0.0.1:3306/[DATABASE_NAME]"
that I didnt really understand where to put. link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql#setting_up_your_local_environment

Comment: Sure. In fact the [documentation for App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql#setting_connection_strings_and_adding_a_library) proposes that same example, using **Flask** and **SQLAlchemy**.

Comment: Now I saw your last edit. That command you mention is used to export an environment variable containing the URI to access the DB with SQLAlchemy. You should substitute the items between square brackets with your corresponding properties.

Comment: I didn't really understand where should I export that connection string

Comment: If you are running the commands from a Linux environment, you just need to export that string from the CLI that you are using for the rest of the commands. If you are doing everything through Cloud Shell, you can export the variable there too.